# Override UIButton backgroundColor property with protocol

Tags: swift3, storyboard, uikit, swift-protocols

I have a protocol like

```
protocol ButtonPresentable {
    var backgroundColor: UIColor { get }
}

extension ButtonPresentable {
    var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        return UIColor.red
    }

}
```

I have a button custom class (draw with IB) that implements my protocol

```
class MyButton: UIButton, ButtonPresentable {
}
```

Why this protocol doesn't 'override' native backgroundColor property ?

I would like to have a default protocol implementation that will set a default background to all buttons. Is there a protocol oriented way to set default values to all UIButton background colors ?

**EDIT**: Actually I do that

```
protocol ButtonPresentable {
    var pBackgroundColor: UIColor { get }
}

extension ButtonPresentable {
    var pBackgroundColor: UIColor? {
        return UIColor.red
    }

    func applyTheme() {
        self.backgroundColor = pBackgroundColor
    }
}

// In my custom view
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    self.applyTheme()
}
```

Comment: Add `override` keyword before `var` declaration. Did you test this?

Comment: @Adolfo Nope! Didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Why this protocol doesn't 'override' native backgroundColor property ?**

Because: *[Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)*

Look at this example:

```
protocol ButtonProtocol {
  var name: String { get }
}

extension ButtonProtocol {
  var name: String {
    return "button protocol"
  }
}

class ButtonClass: ButtonProtocol {
  var name: String = "button class"
}

let button = ButtonClass()
print(button.name) // prints: button class
```

---

**2. Is there a protocol oriented way to set default values to all UIButton background colors ?**

And if you want to **override** the `backgroundColor` of all buttons you could do this: once the button is set with its frame, you can override its background color:

```
extension UIButton {
  open override var frame: CGRect {
    didSet {
      self.backgroundColor = .red
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Aww I missed this! Thanks. Did you have an answer to my question :  Is there a protocol oriented way to override all UIButton background colors ? I understand your example with string but with colors it's not user friendly. I'm updating my question.

Comment: There is no other way that class extension ?

Comment: Extracted from the apple docs (link provided in the answer): `Extensions can add new convenience initializers to a class, but they cannot add new designated initializers or deinitializers to a class. Designated initializers and deinitializers must always be provided by the original class implementation.`

Comment: Sadly :( It will be so awesome to use protocols that way! Thanks